# implementing BLE communication using B-L475E-IOT01A

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide, stm32ldiscovery

I recently bought the B-L475iot01A Discovery board, and I am trying to implement BLE communication using the SPBTLE-RF module integrated on the board. I am a complete beginner when it comes to Bluetooth technology, and I have no idea where to start. I tried using the examples in the software package for the board, but they don't open correctly as STM32CubeIDE projects, and I found a lot of function calls that, when I use Ctrl+click, don't take me to the function itself, so there must be some missing files. Could anyone help me with guidelines or a project that implements BLE on this board? Thank you.

I have no idea how to start and i couldnt find any help from the internet or chatGPT

Comment: This sounds very ambitious for a beginner. Can you get any code to run on the board? Can you blink an LED, or send something on a UART?

Comment: Yes, I have already many project using stm32 but never with BLE

Comment: Update: I updated STM32CubeIDE to the latest version and i can see all the blutooth middleware available